# How can I change the html of the popup from the content script of a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a Chrome extension. However, I'm running into a problem. To reload the UI of the popup when a webpage is loaded. I wanted to realize this by adding a listener to popup.js and sending a message from content.js. The problem is that the message is sent but not received. Can someone help me?

popup.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  document.body.innerHTML = "";
  if (request.text == "reloadSiteTab") {
    reloadSiteTab(request.url);
  }
});
```

content.js:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    {
        "text": "reloadSiteTab",
        "url": location.href
    }
);
```

Comment: Reverse the communication direction.
pupup sends an empty request to content, and content returns information to popup in response.